# when I am inserting into cart with price 0 it is not inserting into cart. Codeigniter Cart Library.

Tags: codeigniter, insert, cart, zero

I am using codeigniter cart library. When I am inserting into cart with price 0, its not inserting into. How can I insert 0 in my cart?

Code Sample:

```
$data = array(
       'id'      => 1,
       'course_id'      => cd0001,
       'qty'     => 1,
       'price'   => 0,
       'name'    => 'English course'              
    );

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

it's possible. I did it. 
just need to modify cart library class in system/libraries/Car‌​t.php. j
ust need to add the following code :

```
if($items['price'] == "") 
{ 
   $items['price'] = 0; 
} 

//after line 198 in codeingiter 2.2.6 at system/libraries/Car‌​t.php
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible insert item in cart with price 0;
alternate you can add discount;

Comment: it's possible. I did it. just need to modify cart library class in system/libraries/Cart.php. 
just need to add the following code : if($items['price'] == "")
  {
   $items['price'] = 0;
  }
after line 198 in codeingiter 2.2.6